Alpha Over white background with translucent materials
Newish to Blender. Creating an animated product demo with translucent and semi-translucent fluid tanks and parts of the product. Using alpha-over node to create a composite white background over the alpha (see node tree) but the translucent materials aren't picking up the white background and so are showing dark grey from Blenders default grey transparency. See pics. When I put white solids behind the tanks the translucency shows up correctly. Issue is only with alpha composite I believe.
Any suggestions to make the translucent materials recognise the alpha-over white background?
Or do I have to create a physical white environment for the translucency to show this?
Thanks for your help




Search this forum for alpha. I suspect you are encoding to a PNG, and PNGs cannot encode alpha. Stick to EXRs and you should be good to go.

Thanks Troy but it's a video not still image. I don't want to show alpha transparency. I want to show a white background over the alpha but my translucent and semi-translucent materials don't pick up the white. They show the Blender dark grey transparency default.

Why not just make the world white? You can do that, you know.

@troy_s What do you mean, PNG can’t encode alpha? They can, and Blender supports it.

You are talking about translucency, not transparency right? The Alpha Over node needs transparency in the alpha channel to overlay something over a background image (or color). But a translucent material is not transparent, it passes the light through but does not make it see-through. So when there is no white light in the background, just grey, you won't see white in the foreground, because you cannot see through and therefore simply exchange the background in post processing.

I’d suggest trying a few frames using EXRs and reading some of the many informative posts here on alpha. I am willing to wager all problems will dissolve.

@TheLabCat I meant what I said. PNGs do not and cannot encode alpha. They encode a mask channel which is not alpha. I would encourage you to read the hundreds of well explained posts here on the subject.

@troy_s Please provide a specific link. You’re asking me to look up something I didn’t know exists, so I don’t know how to search for it.

You might try just setting the world color to white instead of the default grey, but if that doesn’t provide the lighting you want, try turning on the Transparent Glass setting under the Transparent section of the Film panel in Render properties. See the Blender Manual section on the Transparent render setting for more information.
